# Dynamically configuring routing to two set of pods

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a web solution (angular application connecting to rest services) deployed in Kubernetes. I don't use any http sessions in my solution.

On upgrade of my rest services, I need to have both my pods with rest service version 1 and with rest service with version 2 available. Is there any way to setup a gateway/router where I can configure my endpoints dynamically?

I want  `/myendpoint?version=1` to route the traffic to the group of PODs with version 1, and `/myendpoint?version=2` to route the traffic to the other group of PODs.

I must be able to dynamically add new endpoints without stopping the service.

Answer (score 1):

### Separate components by deployment cycle

I would recommend to separate **frontend** app and REST **backend**. (I don't know if you have this already)

By separation, you can roll out new versions independently, with a deployment cycle for each app.

### Two Deployment or N-1 compatibility

In addition, if you want to have multiple versions of the same app available for a longer period, you can deploy them in two different `Deployment`s

e.g. Two `Deployment`, each with its own `Service` and `Ingress` that setup both.

```
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service-v1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /v2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service-v2
          servicePort: 8080
```

Or you can have **N-1** compatibility, so version 2 implements both `/v1/` and `/v2/` API.

### Consider using CDN for static assets

It is usually recommended to deploy frontend on a CDN since it is **static** content. Sometimes your Javascript refers to other Javascript files using [*cache busting*](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting), then it is much easier to handle such setup if all your static content is available from a CDN.

Comment: I'm not very sure if this is right option, perhaps I didn't describe it properly. My backend are RESTServices and I will need a service discovery component like ribbon. My REST services will be updated and new services might be added. With Ingress it looks quite static. I need to deploy a new REST service version and having both the same URL. I need to have RESTService v1 and RESTService v2 living at the same time and setting up the same URL for discovery. When I receive the REST call with v2 parameter, the call has to be redirected to the set of pods where my RESTSerive v2 is deployed

Comment: @Elena my answer describes was you ask for, except Ribbon that I didn't know about, but Kubernetes comes with its own Service Discovery mechanism that I recommend.

Comment: @Elena the Ingrss object gives you that routing, except not in the query parameter, but on path prefix, e.g. `/v2/myendpoint` but you may use a 3rd party Ingress Controller, e.g. Traefik, Istio or Kong.